# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { " in Bootstrap 2.1.0 bundled with Joomla! 3.0

Tags: css, joomla, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Joomla! 3.0, which has Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.0 included. I want to do my own Joomla! template, and I need to use dropdown menus. When I include following CSS/JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shotcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

I get following CSS error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

in `/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css`, line 19

Comment: I think you can ignore that css error

Comment: @MarkoD No, I can't, it occurs in one of the first lines, and Bootstrap isn't working with it.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You have syntax error because you tried to include CSS file as it was JavaScript, so change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also close other link tags properly with `/>`, not with just `>`

Comment: Note you can include jQuery and bootstrap with Joomla through a PHP command just call `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework')` (see docs page here for more info http://docs.joomla.org/Javascript_Frameworks )

Comment: I ran into this when jumping into node development and not paying close enough attention to external resources. Double check your paths, file extensions, and file contents. Make sure everything JavaScript is .js and everything CSS is .css. Also make sure  you're not importing jquery.js as jquery.css. Sounds dumb but it happened to me my first time around so figured it will probably happen to someone else as well.

Comment: Similar issue in that I was adding a Style.Bundle as a Script.Bundle